# Whose portrait hung in Rav Elyashiv's home?

Tags: pictures, rabbis, biography

Whose portrait hung in Rav Elyashiv's home? In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcpSoT9Ek3g) (on the top-right of the video, to Rav Elyashiv's left) you can see the portrait I'm asking about.

The portrait was not hung in the same room that Rav Elyashiv is sitting in, it's in the adjacent room and in the video you are viewing it through a window. (That explains why the portrait seems to move around in a strange way whenever the camera moves.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A friend of mine is a friend of the Eliyashiv family.  He spoke to Rabbi Binyamin Eliyashiv, who said that only two portraits hung in the apartment -- one of the Rav's grandfather, the Lashem, zt'l, and the other of his father-in-law, Rabbi Aryeh Levin, zt'l.  My contact did not show the video to Rabbi Binyamin, but he did show it to rabbaim at Teferes Bechorim, who agreed that the portrait is that of Rabbi Levin.